# Unexpected Beginning of statement - Issue with Syntax?

Tags: sql, phpmyadmin

Currently using PHPMyAdmin, and I am trying to insert some data into a SQL Table.

The error that I am getting is `Unexpected Beginning of Statement (near 'brand')`
Brand is on the second line of the SQL statement.

The data that I am trying to enter:

`INSERT INTO 'vehicles'
('reg_no', 'category', 'brand', 'description', 'dailyrate') VALUES
('BA5923W', 'car', 'Toyota', 'black 4 door 2.6 engine ', '9.99'),
('BA6611A', 'car', 'NISSAN ', '4 Door Saloon, Automatic', '9.99'),
('BM1245a', 'car', 'Golf', NULL, '9.00'),
('GA5955E', 'truck', 'NISSAN CABSTAR 3.0', 'Lorry, Manual ', '18.99')`

cheers

Comment: What are all the single quotes for? Single quotes are for string literals. `vehicles`, `reg_no`, etc. for instance are names and `9.99` is a number. There should be no single quotes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have an syntax error at you query. 
For columns names you should use **Grave Accent** `` ` `` char like

```
(`reg_no`, `category`, `brand`, `description`, `dailyrate`)
```

and for data line **Apostrophe** `'` char like

```
('BA5923W', 'car', 'Toyota', 'black 4 door 2.6 engine ', '9.99')
```

Answer (score 0):

Fixed. I was not closing the block of SQL code that created the table, which comes before this.